# YII 2 application on VirtualHost in fedora 26 OS - The directory is not writable by the Web process

Tags: php, apache, yii, yii2

I develop a small system using YII2 PHP framework on my local host.
folder path "/var/www/html/MY_SITE"

with "yii php serve" command it work fine for this url - localhost:8080

Then I configured a virtual host with documentRoot  "/var/www/html/MY_SITE/web" and host name like "www.my.site.lk"
and configure my host file.
 restart httpd service.

then go to url www.my.site.lk.
but site not working.
YII application error.

**Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/html/RLF_CMS/web/assets**

in /var/www/html/RLF_CMS/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/AssetManager.php

but still woke this url (localhost:8080).

Please help me...

Comment: You may have problems with permision on folders

Comment: are you runing selinux?

Answer (score 1):

Give write permision chmod -R 777 to folder runtime and web/assets